# get last value from variable in php (php tokenizer)

Tags: php, tokenize

I want to make tokens from a php code (as string), so i can get all elements as tokens (http://php.net/manual/de/book.tokenizer.php).

Okay not very difficult - here the following thing (file1.php):

```
<?php

$var1 = "test";
$var2 = $var1;
$var3 = $var2;

//get now the value of $var3

?>
```

and here how to tokenize:

```
<?php

$source = file_get_contents('file1.php');
$tokens = token_get_all($source);

?>
```

Okay i would do just the following:

1. i get the start variable, which is getting the first value... with the following:

```
function read_it($wert, $inhalt, $depth) {

$depth++;

foreach ($inhalt as $key => $value) {

    if (preg_match('/\$([a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*).*?=.*?\$(' . preg_quote($wert, "/") . ');$/i', $value, $ergebnis)) {

        $ret = $ergebnis[1];

        if ($depth < 10) {

            echo $depth;

            read_it($ergebnis[1], $inhalt, $depth);
        }
     }
  }
}
```

Okay - but when i want to get the last value of class member variables etc. its very difficult ... to "follow" the value of this variable... i hope you understand what i mean :)

Comment: can you be more specific what exactly output you require?

Comment: sorry - ive seen it too late - i just want to get the first value of an variable which is outputed somewhere in the file - thx!